# Why python version is different in installed package and in which in use in Atom?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created a virtual environment:

```
conda create -n py38 python=3.8.2
```

Python package that is installed for this environment is:

```
python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.8.2-hc70fcce_0
```

So I hoped to see python version 3.8.2 using following command in the console **when my environment is activated**:

```
python
```

But I see this version:

```
Python 2.7.16
```

And the question is how I can set installed python 3.8.2 instead of 2.7.16?

So here is screenshot of all I said:

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Have you activated the environment in any way…? Creating a conda environment is not going to change how the command `python` behaves globally.

Comment: @deceze hello. Sure)